# Sip Profile Building:Android

Tags: android, profile, sip, voip, builder

I could build a sip profile using SipProfile.Builder class. I used following snippet of code to do it:

```
 if (SipManager.isApiSupported(MyActivity.this)&& SipManager.isVoipSupported(MyActivity.this)) {

SipManager manager=SipManager.newInstance(this);
    SipProfile.Builder builder;try {
                                builder = new Builder(userName,domainName);
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }                                                           manager = SipManager.newInstance(MyActivity.this);
                            builder.setPassword(password);

                            profile = builder.build();
                            try {
                                manager.open(profile);
                            } catch (SipException e) {


                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            manager.register(profile, 30, MyActivity.this);
                        } catch (SipException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "created",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Not Supported",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

It shows as a sip account in the settings/callsettings/Internet call settings. 
Problem is i could not make it as primary account. How can i make it as primary account?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "primary account"?

Comment: while adding sip account manually in the phone, there is an option "Make this as primary account". So, how can i make it programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is account-based (primary email address for person, primary phone number, primary SIP account etc.) so it's stored in the phone's contacts-book.

It seems to me it's an option that is set per-data, per-account (for example: this type of data (email/phone/sip-addr) set it as primary).
You can set data as primary for a contact using [IS_PRIMARY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DataColumns.html#IS_PRIMARY) or [IS_SUPER_PRIMARY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DataColumns.html#IS_SUPER_PRIMARY)

> IS_PRIMARY: Whether this is the primary entry of its kind for the raw
>   contact it belongs to.

The data you should use it on is [ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.SipAddress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.SipAddress.html). I hope that's useful as starting point.